# JSON structure with missing fields - Advice needed- Is it good practice?

Tags: json, mongodb, structure, field

I have this JSON structure:

```
{
  "object1": [
    {
      "field1": {
        "first": null,
        "last": "",
      },
      "array1": [
        {
          "title": "1",
        },
        {
          "title": "2",
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "array1": [
        {
          "title": "4",
        },
        {
          "title": "5",
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Here the field1 is missing in the second object and I also save it in this way on a mongo database. The reason for this decision is that **I only have and need field1 on the first object**. Is it okay or should I just add field1 for other objects but just let them blank?

Comment: How are you going to use this document (i.e. read, update etc.)?

Comment: CRUD - I am using a form with divided sections. So the field1 is a header basically

Comment: Sure I could separate field1 from the array and put it one layer above, but it will not work for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if **field1** might be some kind of pointer (or reference) to first & last document/item.  Personally (and without knowing what you are needing to achieve), I would store this **field1** in each element - with as you suggest null values where appropriate.

For instance - what happens if you can can delete elements - and the first one gets wiped? What will this mean for your structure?

Comment: The first **object1** object can't be deleted and will always be initiated on frontend side with **field1**. I also think to keep the **field1** as null values for the other **object1** objects. The field is meant as an header for a form btw.